# Twitter: Send tweet as Message

Tags: twitter

I want to send a tweet, someone I'm following has tweeted, as direct message without copying it.

So person A tweets 'This is a test'
I send this as direct message to person B

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether it's possible to send a Direct Message via the Twitter API, the answer is yes. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/direct_messages/new for details.  If you're asking something else, you probably need to provide a few more details.

Comment: What I ment is a feature 'Send tweet from other person as direct message to a single person'. Or something like that.

Comment: So you want to spoof another user?  Yeah I don't think Twitter will allow that.

Comment: Hi! I want to use twitter as todo list. Send me tweets i want to read later or messages (like todos).